# How to mock HttpClient request in C#

Tags: c#, mocking, dotnet-httpclient

I have some code like this and I tried using HttpMock and MockHttp but it was of no use is there any otherway to mock the HttpClient Request? I can't edit my code and implement an interface to write UnitTestCases as this would involve modifying lot of other code!

```
public GetData(string url,string data)
{

//does some logic and adds the parameter to URL

string finalurl=url+"?data=data";

using (var client = new HttpClient(new TokenHandler()))
{

       var response = await client.GetAsync(finalurl);
       var responsedata = await 
       response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
       {
             responsefinal = responsedata;
        }
}
return responsefinal;

}
```

Comment: Presumably you want to mock the response, rather than the request?

Comment: Why HttpMock "is of no use"? Seems should work fine here.

Comment: I tried using it but it's not mocking the responses..and Yes I want to mock any response

Comment: The whole purpose of HttpMock is to mock responses, and it does that in your case too. If you start HttpMock on say "http://localhost:9191" and then call `GetData("http://localhost:9191", "somedata") - it will return mocked response.

Comment: The problem is starting the mock server itself is causing issues and I am gonna run my UnitTestCases from the server and we may need to start the HttpMock there also!

Comment: Well if you don't want to start mock server and don't want to change your code in any way - I doubt there is much else you can do.

Comment: starting mock server is the best possible solution I believe but need to find a proper way to stop and start the server

Comment: I did try using HttpMock but there is always an error sending the request..no idea why it's happening! (Connection is getting closed unexpectedly)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid running another server altogether, you can use the overloads of the `HttpClient` constructor. This would require some minor changes to your code (but no need for any interface over your client).

The `HttpClient` constructor takes a an instance of `HttpMessageHandler`. You can create a mock implementation of this that will enable you to inspect the request you get from the client and return an `HttpResponseMessage`, allowing you to mock a variety of scenarios:

```
    public class MockMessageHandler: HttpMessageHandler
    {
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            // Capture request properties, return response
        }
    }
```

You can then pass in a factory method (a function delegate if necessary) to generate instances of your message handler as required:

`public GetData(String url, String data, Func<HttpMessageHandler> handlerFactory)`

And then use it in the HttpClientConstructor:

`using (var client = new HttpClient(handlerFactory()))`

Comment: I think whether it's possible without any minute changes to the code? (I believe it's not)